# Beginner android developer issue

Tags: android

Hi guys I have little problem here while I started learning from this website - http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app.html

When I try to run the app this is what I get from the console - 
`[2013-07-27 18:26:01 - MyFirstApp] Failed to install MyFirstApp.apk on device '0123456789ABCDEF': Read-only file system
[2013-07-27 18:26:01 - MyFirstApp] com.android.ddmlib.SyncException: Read-only file system
[2013-07-27 18:26:01 - MyFirstApp] Launch canceled!`
help anyone ? :(

Comment: Do a adb remount before doing the push should solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already have the Emulator running follow these steps:

- Locate your **adb.exe** file in your Android SDK folder.In Windows
  environment normally your **adb.exe** is inside
  **[Android-SDK-folder]/platform-tools/**. In my case, the **adb.exe** is in
  **C:\android-juno\android-sdk\platform-tools**.
- Put it inside your **[Android-SDK-folder]/platform-tools/** as bellow
  figure:

  [image]
- Now run the **adb.exe** through the command prompt.
- In the command line, go inside the **platform-tools** folder. Execute
  command like:
  **adb install Peribahasa.apk**    //use your apk name here

  [image]

  Later, the apps you just install will be in the emulator.